# Could not find Git in your PATH environment variable - Windows

Tags: git, windows-8

I'm running windows 8 and ran the setup for the Git credential helper found here: http://blob.andrewnurse.net/gitcredentialwinstore/git-credential-winstore.exe

When it runs, in the console window that pops up, I get "Could not find Git in your PATH environment variable.  You can specify the exact path to git by running git-credential-winstore -i C:\Path\To\Git.exe"

I guess I do not know enough about windows here to understand what I should do here.  Ok WHERE do I type this git-credential-winstore -i C:\Path\To\Git.exe, in the GitBash console?

The path to my Git.exe appears to be C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd

Also note that when I installed Git from http://git-scm.com/downloads for windows, I chose the option "Use Git Bash Only" as I'm not really familiar with any of this stuff period.

**UPDATE** - more details

I am referencing this blog post: http://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/how-to-install-octopress-windows/

So the problem is even after I tried the command "Yari 1.9.3" in the command prompt for windows, or in powershell, neither worked:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

you cd into your download directory or wherever you saved git-credential-winstore.exe to:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads>
```

then run

```
 git-credential-winstore -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe"
```

your windows command line will look like this:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads>git-credential-winstore -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe"
```

note the quote marks.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You run commands like this
[from a shell](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells)

With Windows the defacto shell is `cmd.exe`, also known as
[Command Prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt).

This "program" can typically be found at `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

Your instructions likely omit this information because `cmd.exe` has been around for 20 years.

Comment: yea I tried command prompt AFTER I had installed yari, that is.yari was downloaded via the instructions here but it still did not recognize the command yari 1.9.3 in command prompt http://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/how-to-install-octopress-windows/

Comment: the problem is I just wasn't sure if it was the windows command prompt, powershell, or Git Bash to perform the "Yari 1.9.3" command after I had enabled yari for Git.  Because it was not working in any of these command prompts.

Comment: and people don't infer stuff like that when you have installed GitBash and also have windows command prompt and now powershell, give me a break..  People can't assume that everyone knows which to use for what.

Answer (score 0):

You can only install path under uninstall registry key.
some snippet batch script.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET __PA=

IF /i NOT "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" SET __PA=\Wow6432Node
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%F in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE%__PA%\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Git_is1 /v InstallLocation') DO SET gitPath=%%G

ECHO %gitPath%
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the git you have installed is not in the Program Files or Program Files(x86).

It have been installed as a localized version for the particular user and thus your Environment Variable path should be like this.
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you use win7 you should update your path, right click on my computer, advanced system settings, environment variables, in below choose path, and put (`;`) semicolon, then add bin folder in flutter sdk direction, it will be run